# How to encode spaces in E-Mail headers?

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I want to send an e-mail using the mail-function in PHP. The "FROM"-part of the header should contain a name with a space

```
 name with space <mail@server.tld>
```

Unfortunately, some mail clients cannot handle the spaces. Thats why e.g. Thunderbird adds quotes to the name.

```
 "name with space" <mail@server.tld>
```

That works fine, until you add special characters like ÄÖÜ, since they need to be encoded. The follwing would not work:

```
 "name with ÄÖÜ and space" <mail@server.tld>
```

Thats why I tried the function `mb_encode_mimeheader`

```
echo mb_encode_mimeheader("name with"." ÄÖÜ"." and space", "ISO-8859-1", "Q");
# result:
# name with =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=C3=84=C3=96=C3=9C=20and=20space?=
```

That still does not work, since before the first occurence of the special characters, the spaces are still in the string. the correct result schould be:

```
=?ISO-8859-1?Q?name=20with=20=C3=84=C3=96=C3=9C=20and=20space?=
```

Is there a function in PHP that can handle this? or **should I use a mixture of quotes and ´mb_encode_mimeheader´?** Or is there a different way to handle spaces in mailheaders? To be honest, I did not understand the meaning of the different whitespaces mentioned in the RFC822.

Comment: This probably belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sven - you can flag your question and request migration if you agree it should be moved to SO.  Currently, the 2 close votes are to migrate to SO.

Comment: Actually RFC2047 has a special provision for spaces in quoted-printable; they can be represented with underscores. But as noted in my reply, you don't actually need to encode them; the result the code gave you is fine.

Comment: I just realized, that the spaces aren't the problem, but brackets that I'm using. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989915/is-there-an-error-in-phps-imap-fetch-overview-function-when-reading-headers-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need quotes. RFC2047-encoding (i.e. `mb_encode`) handles spaces as well.

(Although for the record, just plain spaces are completely unproblematic; they are not the reason some clients use quoting, which is often completely redundant anyway. So the result with the spaces is actually not incorrect at all.)

Answer (score 1):

As [IETF says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5335), emails only let ASCII characters in their headers. Thus I guess you should ASCII encode your email header.

However, based on the trends that I see in new specifications coming from Internet Engineering Task Force, soon we should see that you might don't need to encode/decode your headers.